# Create editable lable/text?

Tags: java, gwt, java-canvas

I want to add text to a rectangle drawn.

```
canvas.fillRect(...)
```

But I would like the user to enter custom text for this rectangle. But how can I create an editable label in gwt canvas that can take user input?

I want to achieve this in gwt canvas JAVA! Not JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a JTextField with the same location as your Graphics.fillRect().

```
JTextField txtSomething = new JTextField(...)
```

2) Make the JTextField background transparent.

```
txtSomething.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0))
```

3) Run

*There are other ways of doing this, try to research*

Comment: This won't help for a GWT project, which is Java compiled to JavaScript.

Comment: So for web dev I assume I have to create a transparent inputfield overlay which is then rendered into a label (and back for editing)?

Answer (score 0):

The drawstring method here might be of some use :)

http://www.c-point.com/javascript_vector_draw.htm

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I do not want to use JS here. Just from GWT Java.

Comment: No problem :) There is a fillText() method that you can use. I don't like just handing out code to people, so try googling for it. :)

Comment: ok thanks, I see I can call `context.fillText("text");` but still I have no idea how to make this drawn text editable to the user...

Comment: Well then you'll need some form of user input control. That'll be the first thing :)